# Create an array in one function and read it in another without return statements

Tags: java, arrays, reference, return

I'm trying to create an array in one method (or function? Or object? Side question - what's the difference between all these words?) and then use its length in another method (and I'll be using it in other places as well). My teacher told me I don't have to return the array because I'm only modifying the location, so the array isn't destroyed or something. I would declare it in main but then I can't size it after I get the size inputs (I don't think?).

Is anyone following this?

```
public class Update {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("This program will simulate the game of Life.");

    createMatrix();

    // birthAndLive();

    printMatrix();

}

public static void createMatrix() {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please input the size of your board.");

    System.out.println("Rows:");
    final int rows = console.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Columns:");
    final int columns = console.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter a seed:");
    final long seed = console.nextLong();

    boolean[][] board = new boolean[rows][columns];
    Random seedBool = new Random(seed);

}

public static void printMatrix() {

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == false)
                System.out.print(" - ");
            else
                System.out.print(" # ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Next time, don't forget adding a Java tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by passing `board` to your print function.

```
class Update {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("This program will simulate the game of Life.");
        createMatrix();

        // birthAndLive();

        printMatrix();

    }
    public static void createMatrix() {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input the size of your board.");

        System.out.println("Rows:");
        final int rows = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Columns:");
        final int columns = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter a seed:");
        final long seed = console.nextLong();

        boolean[][] board = new boolean[rows][columns];
        Random seedBool = new Random(seed);

        printMatrix(board);
    }

    public static void printMatrix(boolean[][] board) {

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == false)
                    System.out.print(" - ");
                else
                    System.out.print(" # ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

I don't know exactly how much of the code your teacher allows you to change around though. If all functions need to be called from `main`, then you'll either have to put the array creation code inside the main function, or you'll have to resort to return statements or class variables.

Comment: She said we weren't allowed to use any class-level variables. It's killing me because I feel like I could easily do this other ways.

Comment: Ah, in that case, I think she wants you to pass the board to your function as an argument. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Yepyep.  Passing the board to the function is the way to go here.